# WSO2 ANALYTICS EDITOR on WINDOWS 10

Tags: wso2, windows-10, complex-event-processing

[logs files are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml3gI.png)i'm using wso2 analytics editor (hosted in azure cloud) with wso2 CEP local server.when i edit my siddhi apps in the hosted editor but can't save the files no matter what i do.more then that when i try to import samples into the editor shows server error, it happens on windows but not on iOS.

Comment: Can you please include the error log messages?

Comment: Tharik , did you saw the logs files in the link above? it seems that there is a bug in windows for wso2 cep editor , i have tried to use another windows based computer and had the same problems ,save and load sample are not working -we can;t evalute the use of wso for our product ... i'll appreciate if someone from WSO2 could address this issue